# Access K8 Cluster on EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks, nginx-ingress

I am trying to learn to deploy a k8 cluster to eks and access the website through eks and I am receiving a [failed to call webhook error] in my travis-ci log files as well as a [no endpoints available for service "ingress-nginx-controller admission"]. The deployment runs successfully and the pods get launched to the eks cluster, I just cannot figure out how to access the url to the app. I attached some images that I thought might be important for my error.

[CoreDNSError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iD6mf.png)

[Travis-CI Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qXAu.png)

[UnavailableLoadBalancerError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pM7dL.png)

Answer (score 1):

which website do you want to access? What is your web server, and how do you deploy it?

Chances are, that you are missing a loadbalancer to make the web server available.

Comment: Hi Chris thanks for replying I dockerized my nodeJS website with an nginx ingress and then put it in a k8 cluster, I can run it and access it through locahost on my machine but not sure how to do it on aws eks. After launching to eks do I just have to go to ec2 and create a loadbalancer and link it to my eks cluster?

Comment: I would think so, yes. You need a loadbalancer to point to your nginx pod. 
Here is a complete guide to your setup: https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/opensource/network-load-balancer-nginx-ingress-controller-eks/